# Texture Painting - Brush only paints on half of face, sometimes paints on faces not facing viewport

Tags: texture-painting

The problem can be seen in this photo.  It's driving me insane.  I've found a lot of people having similar issues, but nothing as solved not being able to paint on one half of the face:
[image]

Comment: maybe share your file with the image packed inside: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It could be you have a procedural texture set as a brush mask, that would explain the round slope of the area you are able to paint. The paint on wrong sides sounds like you have a need to correct your mesh normals.